# vfork never ends

Tags: c, linux, fork, vfork

The following code never ends. Why is that?

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define SIZE 5
int nums[SIZE] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
int main()
{
  int i;
  pid_t pid;
  pid = vfork();
  if(pid == 0){  /* Child process */
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
      nums[i] *= -i;
      printf(”CHILD: %d “, nums[i]);    /* LINE X */
    }
  }
  else if (pid > 0){  /* Parent process */
    wait(NULL);
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
      printf(”PARENT: %d “, nums[i]);   /* LINE Y */
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**Update:**

This code is just to illustrate some of the confusions I have regarding to `vfork()`. It seems like when I use `vfork()`, the child process doesn't copy the address space of the parent. Instead, it shares the address space. In that case, I would expect the nums array get updated by both of the processes, my question is in what order? How the OS synchronizes between the two?

As for why the code never ends, it is probably because I don't have any `_exit()` or `exec()` statement explicitly for exit. Am I right?

**UPDATE2:**
I just read: [**56. Difference between the fork() and vfork() system call?**](http://dev.fyicenter.com/Interview-Questions/UNIX/Difference_between_the_fork_and_vfork_system.html) 
and I think this article helps me with my first confusion.

> The child process from vfork() system call executes in the parent’s
>   address space (this can overwrite the parent’s data and stack ) which
>   suspends the parent process until the child process exits.

Comment: `int main( void )`  The 80's were a long time ago.

Comment: I think I tend to agree with the Linux man page on `vfork`: "It is rather unfortunate that Linux revived this spectre from the past". Given that `fork` is (in any version of Linux you're likely to be using) a lightweight operation, I'd stop worrying about what `vfork` might or might not do.

Comment: There's one error in your assumptions. "Instead, it shares the address space." This is not correct. It can share the address space, but it doesn't have to. Some operating systems only implement the `vfork` semantics of suspending the parent but still do a copy of the address space like normal `fork`. The reason for that is that there were many bugs caused by sharing the address space (I seem to remember execvp on some system calling malloc and leaking memory in the parent).

Comment: @Art gives an reference if you think `"Instead, it shares the address space."` is not correct.. I like to read more :) In my knowledge [**`vfork()`, creates new process that shares the same address as calling process**](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/vfork.3.asp)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Read http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/sys/kern/kern_fork.c?rev=1.143;content-type=text%2Fplain function `sys_vfork`. If it was sharing the address space the call to `fork1` would have the flag `FORK_SHAREVM`, it doesn't. I know that other operating systems made the same choice, can't recall which ones at this moment. Last time I researched this was 10 years ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `vfork`. That's the simplest advice you can get. The only thing that `vfork` gives you is suspending the parent until the child either calls `exec*` or `_exit`. The part about sharing the address space is incorrect, some operating systems do it, other choose not to because it's very unsafe and has caused serious bugs.

Last time I looked at how applications use `vfork` in reality the absolute majority did it wrong. It was so bad that I threw away the 6 character change that enabled address space sharing on the operating system I was working on at that time. Almost everyone who uses `vfork` at least leaks memory if not worse.

If you really want to use `vfork`, don't do anything other than immediately call `_exit` or `execve` after it returns in the child process. Anything else and you're entering undefined territory. And I really mean "anything". You start parsing your strings to make arguments for your exec call and you're pretty much guaranteed that something will touch something it's not supposed to touch. And I also mean `execve`, not some other function from the exec family. Many libc out there do things in `execvp`, `execl`, `execle`, etc. that are unsafe in a `vfork` context.

*What is specifically happening in your example:*

> If your operating system shares address space the child returning from main means that your environment cleans things up (flush stdout since you called printf, free memory that was allocated by printf and such things). This means that there are other functions called that will overwrite the stack frame the parent was stuck in. `vfork` returning in the parent returns to a stack frame that has been overwritten and anything can happen, it might not even have a return address on the stack to return to anymore. You first entered undefined behavior country by calling printf, then the return from main brought you into undefined behavior continent and the cleanup run after the return from main made you travel to undefined behavior planet.

Comment: Can you explain what execl would supposedly do that is unsafe in vfork? You say "many libc", so can you say if glibc is one of the offenders? When working on a system that doesn't allow memory overcommits, a fork on a memory-intensive application can be prevented by the kernel's memory manager, making vfork a necessary evil. I'd like to know where I can find actual reference to the possible dangers of execl.

Comment: @codetaku check the implementation of your execl. If it touches any global state, especially calling malloc, it is unsafe. This was discovered an eternity ago and almost every operating system called malloc in many of the exec functions. It got attention because a specific exploit surfaced where it could be abused by making some daemon fork and exec a lot which leaked memory and started crashing, lots of libc were fixed back then, but since this is an obscure bug it's quite likely to have crept back in.

Answer (score 8):

To quote from the `vfork(2)` man page:

> The vfork() function has the same effect as fork(), except that *the behaviour is undefined* if the process created by vfork() either modifies any data other than a variable of type pid_t used to store the return value from vfork(), or returns from the function  in which vfork() was called, or calls any other function before successfully calling _exit() or one of the exec family of  functions.

You're doing a whole bunch of those things, so you shouldn't expect it to work. I think the real question here is: why you're using `vfork()` rather than `fork()`?

Comment: In addition to Philip Kendall's answer read this: [**56. Difference between the fork() and vfork() system call?**](http://dev.fyicenter.com/Interview-Questions/UNIX/Difference_between_the_fork_and_vfork_system.html)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Your link is greatly appreciated and helps me solve one of my confusion! Thank you

Comment: @PhilipKendall I am sharing this also from unix.stackexchange.com: [What's the difference between fork() and vfork()?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5337/whats-the-difference-between-fork-and-vfork)

Comment: @zsljulius thanks zsljulius! I will encourage you to read second link too. I just posted in PhilipKendall's answer

Answer (score 1):

From the [official specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/vfork.html):

> the behavior is undefined if the process created by vfork() either modifies any data other than a variable of type pid_t used to store the return value from vfork(),

In your program you modify data other than the `pid` variable, meaning the behavior is undefined.

You also have to call [`_exit`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/_exit) to end the process, or call one of the [`exec`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) family of functions.

Comment: I hate to be the one to say that POSIX is wrong, but POSIX is wrong. Calling anything other than `execve` after `vfork` is bloody dangerous. Look at glibc source for example. Some of the exec* functions call malloc. This means that if we're sharing the address space it's equivalent to calling malloc in the parent. Since the parent doesn't know this, we leak memory. There have been exploits out there 10-15 years ago that trigger something to repeatedly call exec under vfork and run out of memory.

Comment: I got curious and did some code archaeology. The problem was fixed in FreeBSD libc in 1998 which means the exploit was published that year. Linux didn't share address space until 2.2.0 in 1999. This means that glibc never had to deal with a functioning exploit for this bug, which means they never bothered to fix it, so it's still there 15 years later. I bet other libc have the same bug.

Answer (score 0):

The child must `_exit` rather than returning from `main`.  If the child returns from `main`, then the stack frame does not exist for the parent when it returns from `vfork`.

Answer (score 0):

just call the _exit instead of calling return or insert _exit(0) to the last line in "child process". return 0 calls exit(0) while close the stdout, so when another printf follows, the program crashes.