# how to know parent or child process in vfork function

Tags: c, fork, ipc, vfork

I wonder if we use vfork  , how we know child process or parent process , since the resources are shared .
to be more specific , assume the following code :

```
int main()
{
    int pid = vfork();
    if(pid == 0)
    {
       // code for child
     }
    else 
    {
       // code for parent
    }
    return 0;

}
```

in the code above , if the resources are shared , then pid variable will have uniqe value , so is this code is valid ? , since i have seen examples do things as the above code .

Comment: Just read here http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vfork.2.html and read all, it's interesting.

Comment: OT: It's still `int main(void)` at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vfork()` suspends the parent until the child either calls `exec*()` or `_exit()`.

using `vfork()` in this format as we use `fork()` results in program run in infinite loop. it doesn't end.
read this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480053/vfork-never-ends) to get better idea about using `vfork()`.

Comment: "*using vfork() in this format as we use fork() results in program run in infinite loop.*" please elaborate on this.

Comment: @alk the link i provided is a discussion regarding vfork() never ending execution. i run it and we should use exec* in child process part and exit in parent to stop infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

In vfork the parent will wait the child to finish, so there is no need to differentiate.

Answer (score 0):

> is this code is valid ?

Yes. `vfork()` still will make a copy of parent process (conceptually), and as normal `fork()`, in the child process it will return 0, in the parent process the pid of that child process.